# Excessive memory utilization

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory-leaks, neural-network, unet-neural-network

Using this model, I cannot solve the memory consumption problem, even using the dataGenerator the problem remains. The original images have an average weight of 250Kb, the Masks instead 5Kb. I have tried several solutions, but none of them solve my memory consumption problem, which makes it impossible to run this algorithm on the graphics card. Below is the code:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tqdm import tqdm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the U-Net architecture
def unet():
    #inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(860, 808, 1))
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, None, 1))

    # Contracting path
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)
    drop4 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    # Bottom
    conv5 = layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(pool4)
    conv5 = layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)
    drop5 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    # Expanding path
    up6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 2, activation='relu', padding='same')(layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(drop5))
    merge6 = layers.concatenate([drop4, up6], axis=3)
    conv6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(merge6)
    conv6 = layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 2, activation='relu', padding='same')(layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv6))
    merge7 = layers.concatenate([conv3, up7], axis=3)
    conv7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(merge7)
    conv7 = layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    up8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 2, activation='relu', padding='same')(layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv7))
    merge8 = layers.concatenate([conv2, up8], axis=3)
    conv8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(merge8)
    conv8 = layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    up9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation='relu', padding='same')(layers.UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2))(conv8))
    merge9 = layers.concatenate([conv1, up9], axis=3)
    conv9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(merge9)
    conv9 = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)

    # Output
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

    # Create and compile the model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model


class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, base_dir, output_size = (832, 800), shuffle=False, batch_size=10):
        """
        Initializes a data generator object
          :param base_dir: the directory in which all images are stored
          :param output_size: image output size after preprocessing
          :param shuffle: shuffle the data after each epoch
          :param batch_size: The size of each batch returned by __getitem__
        """
        self.base_dir = base_dir
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        self.on_epoch_end()

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.indices = np.arange(1500)
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indices)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(1500 / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        ## Initializing Batch
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, * (800, 832), 1))
        Y = np.empty((self.batch_size, * (800, 832), 1))

        # get the indices of the requested batch
        indices = self.indices[idx * self.batch_size:(idx+1) * self.batch_size]

        for i, data_index in enumerate(indices):
            image_path = os.path.join(self.base_dir, "original/frame_{}.png".format(data_index))
            mask_path = os.path.join(self.base_dir, "filtered/crop_{}.png".format(data_index))

            image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            image = cv2.resize(image, self.output_size)  # Resize to match the desired input size
            image = image.astype(np.float32) / 255.0  # Normalize to the range [0, 1]
            image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=-1)  # Add channel dimension

            img_mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            img_mask = cv2.resize(img_mask, self.output_size)  # Resize to match the desired input size
            img_mask = img_mask.astype(np.float32) / 255.0  # Normalize to the range [0, 1]
            img_mask = np.expand_dims(img_mask, axis=-1)  # Add channel dimension

            X[i] = image
            Y[i] = img_mask

        return X, Y


train_gen = DataGenerator("dataset", (832, 800), batch_size=16, shuffle=True)

# Create the U-Net model
model = unet()

# Define the ProgbarLogger callback
progbar_logger = tf.keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger()

# Train the model
model.fit(train_gen, epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=1500//16, callbacks=[progbar_logger], verbose=2)

# Save the trained model
model.save('unet_model.h5')
```

I've tried different solutions, but I can't solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Reduce the image size, 800x832 is just crazy big, try something like 256x256.